# Is a mock MongoRepository saving objects?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-boot-test

I am using SpringBoot 1.5.9 and try to do Integration testing. Weirdly a MongoRepository.save() method updates the object when called on mock MongoRepository.

I have a Counter Class

```
public class Counter {
     public String id;
     public int seq;

     public void increaseSeq() {
        this.seq += 1;
     }
}
```

And his repository

```
public interface CounterRepository extends MongoRepository<Counter, String>{
    Counter findById(String id);
    List<Counter> findAll();
}
```

And his service

```
@Service
public class CounterService {
    @Autowired private CounterRepository counterRepository;


    public Counter findCounter(String id) {
        return counterRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public int getSeqAndIncrease(String id) {
        Counter counter = findCounter(id);
        if (counter == null) {
            return -1;
         }

        counter.increaseSeq();

        counterRepository.save(counter);

        return counter.getSeq();
    }
}
```

Now, when I do system integration and try to mock the counterRepository, it happens something that I don't expect. The counterRepository.findById() returns a Counter object where the 'seq' field is increased. Why? Does the counterRepository.save() affect the result in any way (the counterRepository is mocked, hence I suppose that save() should not have any effect)?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FlowServiceTest {
    @MockBean private CounterRepository counterRepository;
    @Autowired private CounterService counterService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {  
     Mockito.when(counterRepository.save(any(Counter.class))).then(arg -> arg.getArgumentAt(0, Counter.class));
     Mockito.when(counterRepository.findById("flow")).thenReturn(new Counter("flow", 10));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSavingInDatabase() {
        System.out.println(counterRepository.findById("flow"));

        counterService.getSeqAndIncreaseSafe("flow");
        System.out.println(counterRepository.findById("flow"));

        counterService.getSeqAndIncreaseSafe("flow");
        System.out.println(counterRepository.findById("flow"));
    }
}
```

It prints "10 11 12". Why doesn't it print '10 10 10'?

Comment: IN your test class how have you initialized counterService?

Comment: @pvpkiran yes I initialised it; forgot to write it in the question; not I updated it; Do you see something else that might lead to an error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these lines

```
counterRepository.save(counter);
return counter.getSeq();
```

What you should be doing is this

```
Counter saveCounter = counterRepository.save(counter);
return savedCounter.getSeq();
```

In getSeqAndIncrease method, you are not returning sequence of the saved object.
By doing this you are making your mock statement for **save** useless. Because you are not using the value returned from mock.

Comment: It still does not work. I believe that the problem comes from Mockito. When setting 

'Mockito.when(counterRepository.findById("flow")).thenReturn(new Counter("flow", 10));', 

it might seem intuitive to return a new object everytime, but the return object is initialised only once when the test starts and will be returned at all subsequent calls.

Comment: Then, in my code I do 

counter.increaseSeq();

which increases the 'seq' of found object (this object comes from Mockito). Then at the next call, Mockito returns the firstly initialised object which was updated in the meantime; Mockito does not return a new object as it might seem like.

Comment: Yes, returned object is initialized only once in mockito. So you basically get the same reference everytime, and since it is a reference  not a new object, the values are updated

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - The returned object from mock is initialized only once in mockito. So I basically got the same reference every time, and since it is a reference not a new object, the values are updated.

Complete answer: When setting

```
Mockito.when(counterRepository.findById("flow")).thenReturn(new Counter("flow", 10));
```

, it might seem intuitive to return a new object every time, but the return object is initialised only once when the test starts and will be returned at all subsequent calls.

Then, in my code I do

```
counter.increaseSeq();
```

which increases the 'seq' of found object (this object comes from Mockito). Then at the next call, Mockito returns the firstly initialised object which was updated in the meantime; Mockito does not return a new object as it might seem like.